# Outlook for Mac CardDAV and CalDAV

Tags: ms-office, plugins, caldav, carddav

I'm looking for sync plugins for current Outlook for Mac to make it talk to CardDAV and CalDAV servers. So far I only found plugins for Windows. Any hints?

Comment: Outlook:Mac doesn't support plug-ins.

Comment: Any source on that?

Comment: I was a member of the app team.

Comment: Thanks. Would you then post this as an answer? And besides: If it's true what you say, then why should anyone use Outlook? Only for Exchange? Only the E-Mail part? Without synced contacts? I don't get it...

Comment: No application is for everyone.  You've hit on two of the major use cases for Outlook: Exchange and email-only.  In essence, everyone uses email.  Usage for calendar is much less, and usage of contacts is even less than that.  It is, of course, technically feasible to support CardDAV and CalDAV servers.  The question is whether supporting them is the right thing to do with the development team, or whether to focus on other use cases.

Comment: Strange, seems to me that email and contacts go hand-in-hand.  After all, who is it that I send mail to if not my contacts?  This is why I only use Outlook for Exchange and Spark for all my personal email across clients. (macOS, iOS, watchOS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Outlook for Windows, neither Outlook:Mac 2011 nor Outlook:Mac 2016 support plug-ins.  The closest thing that Outlook:Mac supports is AppleScript, which won't get you to the CardDAV or CalDAV support that you desire.

For my personal usage, I use a combination of Apple Mail (IMAP), BusyCal (CalDAV, which covers both calendar and tasks), and Apple Contacts (CardDAV) in place of Outlook.  I'm not really happy with this combination.  I haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Any changes no that Outlook 2016 for mac supports gmail accounts with contacts and calendar? https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2017/03/01/outlook-2016-for-mac-adds-support-for-google-calendar-and-contacts/